# HTML & JavaScript Uncaught ReferenceError: addTable is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript file which contains some data array and a function. I am using this function to display a table on the html page when it loads and on the click of a button. The error I am getting is:

> GET http://localhost:3000/views/table.js  contracts.html:84
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: addTable is not defined contracts.html:84 onclick

My contracts.html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/portalstyle.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head> 

<body id="contracts">
<div id="wrapper">

<!-- Some Header code here -->

<div id="mytable"></div>

<div id="footer">
    <table id="footer" style="width: 100%">
      <tr>
        <td valign="bottom">Company Name
          <br />Tel Num
          <br />Location, Postcode</td>
        <td>
          <button onclick="addTable(ORDER.orders)">Click me</button>
        </td>
        <td align="right" valign="bottom">
          <a href="#">Home</a> &nbsp;<a href="#">About</a> &nbsp;<a href="#">Help</a> &nbsp;<a href="#">Contact</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<hr />

<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="../views/table.js"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

My javascript function file is called table.js and contains:

```
var ORDER = {
  orders: []
};

function Order(ref, grower, item) {
  this.order_reference = ("o" + ref);
  this.grower_reference = grower;
  this.item_ordered = item;
}

var order1 = new Order(1, "grower2", "item");
ORDER.orders.push(order1);

function addTable(orders) {
  var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
  table.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
  document.body.appendChild(table);

  for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
    var order = orders[i];
    var row = document.createElement("TR");

    var refCell = document.createElement("TD");
    var growerCell = document.createElement("TD");
    var itemCell = document.createElement("TD");

    row.appendChild(refCell);
    row.appendChild(growerCell);
    row.appendChild(itemCell);

    var ref = document.createTextNode(order.order_reference);
    var grower = document.createTextNode(order.grower_reference);
    var item = document.createTextNode(order.item_ordered);

    refCell.appendChild(ref);
    growerCell.appendChild(grower);
    itemCell.appendChild(item);

    table.appendChild(row);
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  addTable(ORDER.orders)
});
```

Where do I need to define addTable? How should I do this?

Also, the error with the GET. This is the line where I include the script. How can I stop this error occurring?

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing `table.js` the correct way? Is it available on the page through developer tools?

Comment: I'm not sure... Sorry. Where should it be on dev tools if it is? On dev tools it appears my contracts.html is under the views folder but there is nothing else in it. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Assuming you are using Google Chrome, check the `Sources` tab.

Comment: Yeah I am. Ok. I can't see table.js ... only my contracts.html page and the css file - How should I reference table then? I've used ../views/table.js as the src for the script tag but that doesn't appear to be working

Comment: I don't know what folder structure you have, so you'll have to figure it out by yourself by trying different paths to your javascript file.

Comment: What is the absolute path to _contacts.html_ and _table.js_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions. They helped me to look at the correct piece of code to find the error so I have no fixed it.

It was an error with my folders and the path I was specifying. I originally had my .js file in my 'views' folder and was using ../views/table.js. This threw the not defined error so I created a new folder called 'js' and copied the file into here and specified it using /js/table.js and now it works.

From what I understand ../ looked in the parent directory of the folder I was in, whereas I needed to be 2 folders up, so starting with just a slash started the search from the root directory, found a folder called js and then found the addTable function as expected.